# Excel VBA Nested Do Loop that reads ahead

Tags: excel, vba, do-while

I am trying to read all values in column G until it finds a blank cell.  If values are "Permits Received" or "Cancelled" then I write "Ready to Build" in column H.  If I encounter anything other than received or cancelled then I write "Missing Permits".  So, I need to read ALL populated cells in column G and write ready... or missing... in column H.  The problem with my code is 1) its probably not the best approach, and 2) it only reads the first cell in column G then writes the output.

This is for an automated workbook that works like a champ except for this loop.  I have been goofing with For Next, Do While and For Each with varying success but the code below is the closest I've been.

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("$G$2:$G$" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count) ' Set range to all used rows in column G

    For i = 2 To rng.Rows.Count
        Do While Cells(i, 7).Value = ""
            If Cells(i + 1, 7).Value = "Permits Received" Or Cells(i + 1, 7).Value = "Cancelled" Then
                Cells(i, 8).Value = "Ready to Build"
            Else: Cells(i, 8).Value = "Missing Permits"
            End If
            i = i + 1
            If i = rng.Rows.Count Then Exit For ' Without this code it will read all rows, not just used rows
        Loop
    Next i
```

I expect the loop to read all column G values then decide if it is "Ready to Build" or "Missing Permits".  The code runs to the 35766 then errs with Overflow if the Exit For is not included.

(new) I only need one output line (col H) per each line or group of lines (col G).  The attached image shows how the output should look.  Thank you so, so much for looking at this!!!  I've been staring at it for a week!

[Example of input and correct output, need code for column H](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIk79.png)
[Example of output from latest solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPHG0.png)

Comment: Not clear if in the cases where a group has "Permits Received" or "Cancelled", the value in column H is "Ready to Build" because "Permits Received" or "Cancelled" is found in the first line of the group. What if the first line of the group is "Permits Submitted" and only the last line is "Permits Received" or "Cancelled", would the column H for that group be "Ready to Build" or “Missing Permits”?

Comment: Only if all lines in the group are "Permits Received" or "Cancelled" is it supposed to be "Ready to Build".  If any line or lines in the group are other than that then the FQNID_Status is "Missing Permits".  A line or group of lines can contain any status but if even one "Permits Submitted" or "Preliminary Designed" is included then the status is "Missing Permits".

Comment: Would you please make up your mind, you changed the requirements again, the new image shows very different results than the previous one.

Comment: See updated answer as per the latest image.

Comment: Your last solution worked perfectly!  Thank you so much for your time and effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution based on the image published:**

Assuming that the default value for any *FIB:BUR* group is *"Missing Permits"*, unless all of its *FIB:PERMITs* have the values *"Permits Received"* or *"Cancelled"* then it should be marked as *"Ready to Build"*.

This proposed solution uses [AutoFilter object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.autofilter) combined with the [Range.SpecialCells method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells). To create a range in which the groups are separated by [Range.Areas property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.areas).
Then it uses `For…Next` and the `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` to validate the presence of *"Permits Received"* or *"Cancelled"*, and [Range.Offset Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060(v=office.15).aspx) to set the resulting value for the group.

```
Sub Solution()
Dim rSrc As Range, rTrg As Range
Dim rArea As Range
Dim bCnt As Byte  'Change data type to long if the number of FIB:PERMITs by FIB:BUR exceeds 255

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")    'change as required
        If Not (.AutoFilter Is Nothing) Then .Cells(1).AutoFilter
        Set rSrc = .Cells(2, 7).Resize(-1 + .UsedRange.Rows.Count, 2)
    End With

    With rSrc
        .Columns(2).ClearContents
        .Offset(-1, 0).Resize(1 + .Rows.Count).AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
        Set rTrg = .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .AutoFilter
    End With

    For Each rArea In rTrg.Areas
        bCnt = 0
        With WorksheetFunction
            bCnt = .CountIf(rArea, "Cancelled")
            bCnt = bCnt + .CountIf(rArea, "Permits Received")
            rArea.Cells(1).Offset(-1, 1).Value2 = _
                IIf(bCnt = rArea.Rows.Count, "Ready to Build", "Missing Permits")
    End With: Next

    End Sub
```

**Answer to original question**

Instead of using a `Do…Loop` within the `For…Next`, you could have used `IF…ELSEIF` or  [Select Case statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement). This proposed solution uses `Select Case`

```
Sub Solution_1()
Dim rTrg As Range, lRow As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")    'change as required
        Set rTrg = .Cells(2, 7).Resize(-1 + .UsedRange.Rows.Count, 2)
    End With

    With rTrg
        For lRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
            Select Case .Cells(lRow, 1).Value2
            Case vbNullString   'NO ACTION!
            Case "Permits Received", "Cancelled"
                .Cells(lRow, 2).Value2 = "Ready to Build"
            Case Else
                .Cells(lRow, 2).Value2 = "Missing Permits"
    End Select: Next: End With

    End Sub
```

However, I try to avoid `For…Next` whenever is possible, so this alternate solution uses 
[AutoFilter object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.autofilter)  combined with the [Range.SpecialCells method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells).

```
Sub Solution_2()
Dim rTrg As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")    'change as required
        If Not (.AutoFilter Is Nothing) Then .Cells(1).AutoFilter
        Set rTrg = .Cells(2, 7).Resize(-1 + .UsedRange.Rows.Count, 2) ' Set range to all used rows in column G
    End With

    With rTrg

        .Offset(-1, 0).Resize(1 + .Rows.Count).AutoFilter
        .Columns(2).Value2 = "!"
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="!"

        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=Cancelled", _
            Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Permits Received"
        .Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value2 = "Ready to Build"

        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
        .Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value2 = "Missing Permits"

        .AutoFilter Field:=1
        .Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents

        .Cells(1).AutoFilter

    End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: Both the first and second solutions generate the same output, which is almost correct. I think an image of the input and correct output would help dramatically in explaining my problem. How can I post an image to this thread??

Comment: @Tom, to add an image, edit your question, then in the **Body** section click the icon with a landscape figure (the no. 6), then follow the instructions.

Comment: EEM - I have added an image above to show the input data and expected output.  I sincerely appreciate you helping with this!!!  Hopefully the attached image will clarify the output I am looking for.  Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

I've encountered a similar issue when using a for loop to iterate rows like that when I use an integer as the data type for my loop index variable.  The Excel integer data is 2-bytes in length and has a range of -32,768 to 32,767.  Perhaps your mention of "35766" was a typo for 32766 or 32767.  If you change your variable 'i' from an int to a long, I would expect your issue to go away.

If this macro is something for your personal use rather than something others will be using, I've often used the following approach to iterate down one column and modify another cell that's on the same row:

```
Do While IsEmpty(ActiveCell.value) = False
    If ActiveCell.value = "X" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).value = "M"     ' ActiveCell.Offset(row_offset, column_offset)
    ElseIf ActiveCell.value = "Y" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).value = "N"
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate            ' From currently active cell, activate the next cell one row down
Loop
```

Before running a macro using this technique, you'd have to activate the first cell in the column being evaluated - which becomes the cell first evaluated as the ActiveCell.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Both the first and second solutions generate the same output, which is almost correct. I think an image of the input and correct output would help dramatically in explaining my problem. How can I post an image to this thread??